# Google Cloud PubSub Streaming Pull hangs forever

Tags: c++, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have this simple code to pull the messages from Google PubSub Subscription:

```
#include "google/pubsub/v1/pubsub.grpc.pb.h"
#include "google/pubsub/v1/pubsub.pb.h"
#include "grpc++/grpc++.h"

#include "base/logging.h"

int main() {
  auto creds = grpc::GoogleDefaultCredentials();
  auto stub = std::make_unique<google::pubsub::v1::Subscriber::Stub>(
      grpc::CreateChannel("pubsub.googleapis.com", creds));
  grpc::ClientContext context;
  std::unique_ptr<
      grpc::ClientReaderWriter<google::pubsub::v1::StreamingPullRequest,
                               google::pubsub::v1::StreamingPullResponse>>
      stream(stub->StreamingPull(&context));

  google::pubsub::v1::StreamingPullRequest request;
  request.set_subscription("my_subscription");
  request.set_stream_ack_deadline_seconds(10);
  stream->Write(request);

  google::pubsub::v1::StreamingPullResponse response;
  size_t count = 0;
  while (stream->Read(&response)) {
    google::pubsub::v1::StreamingPullRequest ack_request;
    for (const auto& message : response.received_messages()) {
      ack_request.add_ack_ids(message.ack_id());

      if (++count % 1000 == 0) {
        LOG(Info, "count: " << count << " message_size: " << message.message().data().size());
      }
    }
    stream->Write(ack_request);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It turned out that `while (stream->Read(&response))` doesn't work forever and stops after ~30 minutes (I don't know why that happens). I tried to wrap the code in `while (true)` so messages will be pulled in an infinite loop but it turned out that the second iteration can't pull any messages (I see in Google Cloud monitoring that messages are coming).

What is wrong with this code?

I know that GCP didn't implement C++ client yet and StreamingPull is a low level API but I don't wanna wait until they make it (it's unclear when it'll happen) and also don't wanna switch to other language (my application is in C++).

Comment: Does the code stop after 30 minute **without new message**? Or do you receive messages during this period?

Comment: Please provide more info.
Does the while loop stop always after 30 minutes? What is the shortest/longest time it's been active?
Do you get any logs or error messages when it stops?
Have you made sure that you are still getting messages after it stopped?
Have noticed any patterns? For example, does it stop when you notice a higher or lower data throughput?
Have you made sure that the "while(true)" approach always stops exactly at the second iteration?

Comment: As you've mentioned, there's no official supported C++ library for Pub/Sub, so the best suggestion is to switch to any other of the supported languages.
Alternatively, I found this other custom library for C++, you could give it a try:

https://github.com/sandvikcode/pubsuber

Comment: RE  guillaume blaquiere:


I'm receiving messages during all ~30 minutes. The message flow doesn't stop.


RE  Fcojavmelo:


The while loop stops after ~30 minutes without any messages/errors and I know there are other messages available in the subscription. It stops in the range of 25-35 minutes. Yes I see messages in Google Cloud UI which are accumulating when the loop stops to process messages. No patterns I noticed of, throughput is the same. Yes, I made sure that after the first iteration in while (true) no messages are get.

Comment: RE: Fcojavmelo

I can't switch whole big application I have to another language, also interprocess communication doesn't sound like a reasonable solution. I can try pubsuber but I think it'd be better to build a solution over the native Google library than any other third party library.

Answer (score 0):

Streaming connections to GCP can be closed for a variety of reasons, e.g. transient network issues or max TTLs on connection lifetimes. A stream should not be expected to be open indefinitely.

When `stream->Read(&response)` returns false, that's an indication that the stream has been closed [[source]](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc__impl_1_1internal_1_1_reader_interface.html#a005a2778e6005e25555dd0fdeb2db1a7). Your code should then recreate the stream to continue pulling messages.